# 'null' is not an object with Google chart (issue with select menu, onchange event)

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, google-visualization, onchange

I'm using the following Script:

```
<header>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
</header>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Header');
    data.addColumn('number', '');
    data.addColumn('number', '');
    data.addRows([
      ['Monday',300,43],
      ['Tuesday',250,545],
      ['Wednesday',122,78],
      ['Thursday',348,92],
      ['Friday',23,61],
      ['Saturday',39,93]
    ]);
    var options = {
      title: '',
      hAxis: {title: '',  titleTextStyle: '#efede9'},
      backgroundColor: '#efede9',
      legend: 'none'
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('area_chart_google'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>

<div id="area_chart_google" class="area-chart"></div>
<body>
```

I cannot use the script inside Header because I'm using dynamic content.

I figure it out to work when I first load the page, and after refreshing it. My problem now is that I'm using a select menu with an onchange event, similar to this:

```
<select id="form_frame1" name="frame1" onchange="getChart(this);">
 <option value="area_chart_google" >Area Chart</option>
 <option value="area_chart_2" selected="selected">Stacked Chart</option>
</select>
```

My getChart function is:

```
function getChart(selection) {
 if (selection.value == "area_chart_2") {
    document.getElementById('area_chart_2').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('area_chart_google').style.display = 'none';
}

 else {   
    document.getElementById('area_chart_2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('area_chart_google').style.display = 'block';
   }
}
```

So, once my area_chart_google is not displayed (display: none) and I select it, I get the error:

```
*Firebug* google-visualization-errors-all-1 
*Chrome* Cannot read property 'length' of null
*Safari* 'null' is not an object
```

I guess is something with **getElementById**, so I tried using:

```
window.onload = function(){ javascript code here }
```

And also:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   javascript code here
});​
```

Nothing happen. I get no error but the Chart don't appear.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
function getChart(selection) {
  if (selection.value == "area_chart_2") {
  document.getElementById('area_chart_2').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('area_chart_google').style.display = 'none';
}

else {   
  document.getElementById('area_chart_2').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('area_chart_google').style.display = 'block';
  drawChart(); //call this function when using this Google Chart
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the Google API first:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

You also should have proper `<body>` and `<head>` tags in your script.

Otherwise the code is fine. The below works fine for me:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Header');
        data.addColumn('number', '');
        data.addColumn('number', '');
        data.addRows([
          ['Monday',300,43],
          ['Tuesday',250,545],
          ['Wednesday',122,78],
          ['Thursday',348,92],
          ['Friday',23,61],
          ['Saturday',39,93]
        ]);
        var options = {
          title: '',
          hAxis: {title: '',  titleTextStyle: '#efede9'},
          backgroundColor: '#efede9',
          legend: 'none'
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('area_chart_google'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <div id="area_chart_google" class="area-chart"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using the jsapi header (it wasn't explicit in my question). There are two things different than yours, one is that I cannot use the script code inside the header (because I'm using dynamic content and some other reasons). The second thing is that I you are calling google.load twice (I did it too, but it didn't make a difference). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but try doing :

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
//..your drawChart() function code here
$(document).ready(function() {
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
});
```

I hope you have already included following script in your header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this, I get no error but the chart does not appear (and yes, I'm including the jsapi header!). Thank you!